# How to implement nested q promise in node js?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Can we implement following q promise nesting in node js? If we cannot, are there any alternatives to achieve the following?

```
var array1 =[--*some data*--];
var array2=[],array4=[];

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
 var promise1 = generatePromise1();
 array2.push(promise1); 
}

Q.all(array2).then(function(array3){
 for(var j=0;j<array3.length;j++)
 {
  var promise2 = generatePromise2();
  array4.push(promise2);
 }

 Q.all(array3).then(function(array4){
  return array4;
 })
})
```

Comment: How can you ask to "achieve the following" without knowing whether it works or not?

Comment: Can you describe in human language what do you want?

Comment: i tried the above earlier but it didnot return array4

Comment: @rdkrosan: Did not return it *where*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement it like this (sans the typoes in the variable numbering).
But I would advise to always `return` the promises from `.then` callbacks, and unnest the callbacks through that:

```
var array1 = [ /*some data*/ ];
var array2  = array1.map(generatePromise1);

Q.all(array2).then(function(array3) {
    var array4 = array3.map(generatePromise2);
    return Q.all(array4);
}).then(function(array5) {
    … // use result here
})
```